# Error to consume automation variable Dynamics 365 Business Central

Tags: dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I create an automation variable in Dynamics 365 Business Central On Premise.

This code work fine the first time but then an error apear.

Code:

```
EVALUATE(_PC, PCStr);

CREATE(_Export, TRUE, TRUE);

_Export.process(_PC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because you never **clean** your automation variable. You have to use `CLEAR()` sentence.

**Example:**

```
EVALUATE(_PC, PCStr);
CLEAR(_Export);//to clean your automation
CREATE(_Export, TRUE, TRUE);
_Export.process(_PC);
```

Comment: Isn’t it cleared automatically when variable goes out of scope?

Comment: It depends, I imagine that it is a global variable the code is executed with a button for example and you do not clean the variable you have an error: "The automation variable has already been create", If the variable is local it works fine.